# pass data from one tabbar viewcontroller to another tabbar viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have two tabbar items song,player on a tabbar controller . What i want to do is ,when i select a song in song view controller then the player tabbar must be selected and the song must be passed to player tabbar viewcontroller and play. How to achieve this?

Comment: show your code, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set url before pushing your viewcontroller. Try below code, it should work now.

```
  if(!viewContObj) viewContObj=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]; 
viewContObj.url =[NSURL URLWithString:albumURLstring];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewContObj animated:YES]; 
 [viewContObj playLiveStream:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your class and in another tab cretae this set string method.

```
 ViewController *viewController=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
//Pass the string to next viewcontroller
[viewController setString:albumURLstring];
```